# Efficent way to query an sqlite database with an R vector

Tags: sqlite, r

I have a vector of values in R and want to get responding values from a sqlite database. I use the following code.

```
values = c()

for (a in keys)
{
    result <- dbGetQuery(con," SELECT content FROM aacontent WHERE Id=?",a)
    values = c(values,results)
}
```

Unfortunatly, this code is very slow. Is there a more efficent way to do this?

Thanks,

Johannes

Comment: I'd probably change your SQL query from `Id =` to `Id IN (...)`. Are the values in `keys` characters, numbers,...?

Comment: They are characters. Are you suggesting to put the whole vector into the brackets after IN? Would that retain the correct order??

Comment: Probably not (it will depend on the what order `keys` is in). I would select both `content` and `Id` in the query and then sort the result, either in SQLite, or after the fact in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If aacontent isn't very large then read it all into R and use something like R's match function, or the sqldf function, or data.table functions

If aacontent is too large for that, and keys is small-ish, then write keys to an sqlite table and do a join query. You might benefit from creating an index on one or both of them.

Comment: Thanks, writing the keys and doin a join query was extremly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The are certainly pre-built tools for SQL querying tasks like this from R (since you're using SQLite, I'd be sure to check out **sqldf**), but in my experience I just end up writing lots of little helper-wrapper functions for building queries.

For instance, in your case, your problem isn't really the R piece, it's that you want to roll all the values in `keys` into one query. So you'd want a query that looks more like:

```
SELECT content FROM aacontent WHERE Id IN (val1,val2,...)
```

and then the trick is using `paste` in R to build the `IN` clause. I tend to just use a simple wrapper function on `dbGetQuery` that uses the `...` argument and `paste` to stitch queries together from various pieces. Something like this:

```
myQuery <- function(con,...){
    arg <- list(...)
    res <- dbGetQuery(con,paste(arg,collapse = ""))
    res
}
```

So that it's a bit easier to stitch together stuff when using `IN` clauses:

```
myQuery(con,"SELECT content FROM aacontent WHERE Id IN (",
             paste(keys,collapse = ","),"))
```

Note that it's a bit harder if the values in `keys` are characters, since then you need to do some more work with `paste` to get single quotes around each element, but it's not that much more work.

This advice is all more relevant if the db in question is fairly small; if you're dealing with bigger data, Spacedman's suggestions are probably more worth looking into.

Comment: @Spacedman Depends on the particulars of the setup. In my case, my db is only ever queried by a person physically sitting at my computer, so I tend not to worry about such things, since if someone bad actually has my computer I have bigger problems than an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Yes, but its not just malicious attacks you have to worry about. Once you start constructing strings to pass to SQL expressions you have to worry about escaping quotes as well as semicolons and so forth. Are there sql escape functions, or placeholder replacement techniques in R's DB packages?